# Select MAX Value for Each ROW - Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have one doubt.
I need to find what is the latest occurrence for a specific list of Customers, let's say to simplify, I need it for 3 Customers out of 100.
I need to check when it was the last time each of them got a bonus. 
The table would be:

```
EVENT_TBL
```

Fields: `Account ID`, `EVENT_DATE`, `BONUS ID`, ....

Can you suggest a way to grab the latest (`MAX`) `EVENT DATE` (that means one row each)

I'm using `SELECT...IN` to specify the Account ID but not sure how to use `MAX`, `Group BY` etc etc (if ever needed).

Comment: example code and desired results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Account_id ORDER BY event_date DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   EVENT_TBL t
  WHERE  Account_ID IN ( 123, 456, 789 )
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: it returns: "rn Invalid Identifier)

Comment: @MorganForever did you include the `AS rn` part?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
with AccountID_Max_EVENT_DATE as (
 select AccountID, max(EVENT_DATE) MAX_D
 from EVENT_TBL 
 group by AccountID
)
SELECT E.* 
FROM EVENT_TBL E
INNER JOIN AccountID_Max_EVENT_DATE M 
ON (E.AccountID = M.AccountID AND M.MAX_D = E.EVENT_DATE)
```

Comment: This uses a self-join and may require two table scans. Also, if there are multiple entries with the same (maximum) date then this will return more than one row per account.